# How to prove the equality $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}| = \frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How to prove this equality?

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}| = \frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$

related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703587/epsilon-delta-proof-that-lim-x-to-a-sqrt-x-sqrt-a)

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Note that in your equality $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}>0$ and if $n>0$, then $n|m|=|nm|$. So, multiply both sides by the positive quantity $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}$ and simplify using the formula for the difference of squares: $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Alternatively, you can arrive at the right-hand side of the equality by multiplying $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|$ by $\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$:

$$
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|=
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|\cdot 1=
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}|\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}=\\
\frac{|(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}=
\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}.
$$

Of course, all this is true as long as $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both $a$ and $x$ are positive.  Two cases (1) $x \gt a$ and (2) $x\le a$.

Case(1) becomes $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}=\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$.  Clear the denominator and get $x-a=x-a$.  Since $x\gt a$, $x-a=|x-a|$

Case(2) becomes $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}$.  Clear the denominator and get $a-x-a-x$. Since $x\le a$, $a-x=|a-x|=|x-a|$.